# How do I retrieve the name of a Semaphore

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

My code creates a number of Semaphores when it initializes.  Each one is associated with a  ftp server that my system will communicate with from multiple workflows.
As different instances of the same workflows start I inject the semaphores into the workflows depending on which ftp site that workflow is going to communicate with.

I'm getting a situation where it looks like 2 or more workflows which should contain the same Semaphore are trying to access the ftp servers more times than the capacity of the Semaphore should allow.

I've named the Semaphores because I thought I could retrieve the name at the point where the ftp connection is made so that I can check that the correct Semaphore is in the right workflow.

How do I access the name of a Semaphores?

I tried to build an object that inherits from Semaphores and add a name field but this does not work as Semaphore is Sealed

```
public class MySemaphore : System.Threading.Semaphore
{
   string SemaphoreName = "Bob";
}
```

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you are doing.  Please post some code as to how you are using the semaphore.

Comment: It looks like you are using semaphores in place of threads.

Comment: I don't understand either.  Is each 'workflow' a different process?

Comment: Just curious...why all the semaphores in the first place?

Comment: @ Martin James . They are WWF workflows @Brian Gideon Each Semaphore is the gatekeeper to a specific ftp site (I have 50).  100s of files can be moving through the system at any one time so I need to limit how many connections are made to a single ftp site at a time.  Keeping the connections open and pooled is not an option as some sites are used every few seconds and some not for weeks and which is which varies with use. @ Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy No @ cadrell0 An answer below has sorted th eproblem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using .NET 4.0 then use `SemaphoreSlim` instead. It is not sealed.

If you must use `Semaphore` then you will have to create your own class without subclassing it. You will have to punt on the polymorphism so it will not work inside `WaitHandle.WaitAny` for example, but it is a viable workaround.

```
public class MySemaphore
{
  private Semaphore underlying;

  public MySemaphore(int initialCount, int maximumCount)
  {
    underlying = new Semaphore(initialCount, maximumCount);
  }

  public bool WaitOne()
  {
    return underlying.WaitOne();
  }

  public int Release()
  {
    return underlying.Release();
  }

  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this is for debugging purposes, to name your semaphores somehow, you can use a dictionary keyed by each Semaphore at the semaphore construction, i.e. use

```
 public static readonly Dictionary<Semaphore, string> SemaphoreNames 
            = new Dictionary<Semaphore,string>();

...
    Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0, 200);
    SemaphoreNames[sem] = "Bob";
...
```

You can access their names from SemaphoreNames[someSemaphore]. If this is just used for debugging, I'd place the extra lines between #ifdef DEBUG and #endif.

Answer (score 0):

I went with this.

```
public class SemaphoreSlimNamed : SemaphoreSlim
{
    public string name;

    public SemaphoreSlimNamed(int InitialCapacity, int MaxCapacity) : base(InitialCapacity, MaxCapacity)
    {

    }
}
```

Thanks for the suggestions